# Unable to enter back-end code of dropdownlist in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to enter the back-end codes of the dropdownlist which i just dragged from the toolbox. 
I coded a dataset on the page load and i need to declare a sqldataadapter to the dropdownlist in order to display out the value. However, despite double clicking the icon multiple times, my back-end code didnt appear.
Why is this the case?

Here is a simple source code for my dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLTOC" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the 'Lightning' icon and selecting the appropriate action.

[image: Actions]

Ignore the fact that i'm using a Grid control. It will work with all controls.

Comment: I went to click the icon as you state above and the back-end codes still doesn't appear. 

http://imgur.com/gHpNzGy

Comment: Try clicking the textbox beside the name. Like this. http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/9297/ghpnzgy.png

Comment: Yeah, Just double click it. An action method should auto generate.

Comment: Actually it doesn't auto-generate. I hard-code this code into the source code of the dropdownlist and it works

     OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLTOC_SelectedIndexChanged"

Comment: Yep, that'll work as well. But in normal circumstances, double clicking will generate. It works on my side.